# c++ function resolution selects templated version over plain function

Tags: c++, function, templates, resolution

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void f(T t)
{
  (void)t;
  std::cout << "templated f(T)\n";
}

template<typename T>
void entry(T t)
{
  f(t);
}

void f(double d)
{
  (void)d;
  std::cout << "normal f(double)\n";
}

int main()
{
  double d = 0.0;
  entry(d);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> templated f(T)

I find this surprising, because I thought that the plain function will be selected over any templated version. Why does this happen?

Another thing I noticed while playing around is that: if I put the normal function `void f(double)` before the templated `void entry(T)` function the code will call the normal function, basically outputting:

> normal f(double)

Therefore my other question: why does the order matter in this particular example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`f` is a dependent name, since it depends on `t` whose type is a template parameter. The name lookup rules for dependent names are given in [temp.dep.res]/1:

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:
>
> - Declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template.
> - Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the
>     instantiation context (14.6.4.1) and from the definition context.

In other words, normally name lookup inside a template only finds names that have been declared before the template definition (which is not that surprising, since it's the same as for non-templates). The second bullet point allows names declared after the template definition to be found, but only when ADL occurs. This won't be the case when the argument is a fundamental type such as `double`.

Comment: Ok,... however I noticed that lookup inside a template will find a name even *after* the declaration of the template if it another template, even a specialization of a template with a fundamental type such as `double`. I checked this by changing the normal function into a specialized template: `template<> void f(double)`. Outcome is the specialized template is called, even though it is past the declaration point of the calling code.

Comment: @Edenbridge Name lookup always finds the primary template. Matching of specializations occurs after name lookup and has a different rule: if the template is instantiated before the best matching partial specialization is declared, then the program is ill-formed with no diagnostic required. If you have any more concerns, please post a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The overload for `f(double)` is not visible to the compiler when the `entry(T)` template is parsed. Therefore, it won't participate in overload resolution when the `entry(T)` template is instantiated. This is just an obscure rule when it comes to resolving overloads in a template instantiation context. In order for an overload to be considered, it has to already have been visible in the translation unit before the template definition was parsed.